# Two Facebook like buttons on the same page with two different thumbnails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have two different products "Prod_A" and "Prod_B" on the same page, say

www.xyz.com/index1.html

On this page are two images for these products and small descriptions.

I need two like buttons for both products, both like buttons should refer to the page where they are located ( www.xyz.com/index1.html ), but both buttons should have different og:images  and descriptions.

I have found some solutions for multiple buttons, but they refer to different pages and don't have pictures included.

thanks!

PS:
A small working example would be greate

Edit:
@DMCS said (see comment) that this is not possible. would it work, when I create a dummy page for the second product www.xyz.com/index2.html which would redirect to the page www.xyz.com/index1.html?
I this case I would have two pages is it then possible?

Comment: A small working example would be impossible as you have one page for two products.  You will need a separate page for each product for the og tags to be properly read.

Comment: @DMCS ok. is it at least possible to have two like buttons (one for each product) without the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you need to create as many dummy pages as you have like buttons on your main page. Each of these pages includes all the OG tags you need including descriptions and images. You then use a redirect to take the user back to the page with the buttons.

Use the [facebook like button tool](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to create the buttons using the url of each dummy page. Here's an example dummy page:-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head><title>This is a dummy page to hold the OG tags</title>

<meta property="og:title" content="This is the text the like button will show in FB when liked"/>

<meta property="og:site_name" content="the site name shown, the from name in FB"/>

<meta property="og:url" content="http://www,yoursite.com/dummp_01.html" />

<meta property="og:image" content="http://www,yoursite.com/dummyimage01.jpg" />

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.redirect_to_url_that_has_all_the_like_buttons.com">

</head><body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you add some variable to the address, and then do some switching using php?

For example

Like 1 links to: http://xyz.com/index.php?like1=true
Like 2 links to: http://xyz.com/index.php?like2=true

then in php on the index.php page just use an if statement...

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['like1']) { ?>
[your like 1 og tags here]
<?php } else if (isset($_GET['like2']) { ?>
[your like 2 og tags here]
<?php } ?>
```

*NOTE* Of course this solution would work also for other languages besides php

Answer (score 0):

> when I create a dummy page for the second product
>   www.xyz.com/index2.html which would redirect to the page
>   www.xyz.com/index1.html? I this case I would have two pages is it then
>   possible?

Yes, this is a good idea.  The facebook linter does not run any javascript, so it would pick up the og tags properly.  And when a user comes to that page, they will get redirected by javascript and see the page with the two products.