# Facebook Like-Button SDK (JavaScript), how do you separate the like buttons between articles on the same page

Tags: javascript, html

To clarify, I am using facebooks like-button SDK (JavaScript) on one of my sites pages (gameday.html).  I currently have 2 different articles on the page with the like-button set to both articles. When I like one of the articles, it also likes the other.

The following is the HTML I am using for the Like-Button SDK:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://scarletandmaize.com/gameday.html" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

I figure that it is doing this because the data-href is set to the entire gameday.html page. Just don't know if I can or how to separate it between the 2 articles on the page?! Thanks for any help!

Comment: This has been asked several times on SO already. Did you try searching? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336696/two-facebook-like-buttons-on-the-same-page-with-two-different-thumbnails), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656151/multiple-facebook-opengraph-objects-on-the-same-page), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809161/how-to-put-multiple-facebook-like-buttons-with-counter-on-same-page).

Comment: sorry, guess i wasnt searching correctly